# Joining two pandas draframes based on a timestamp being between two others

Tags: pandas, dataframe, left-join

I have two data frames like below. I want to left join the `period_df` to `records_df` based on the equality of the two columns `Day` and `Direction`, and also the `Reference time` from `records_df` being between the `Start time` and `End time` from the `period_df` data frame

```
period_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday'],
                           'Direction': ['In', 'Out', 'In', 'Out', 'In'],
                           'Period': ['Period 1', 'Period 2', 'Period 3', 'Period 2', 'Period 1'],
                           'Start time': ['1900-01-01 05:01:00', '1900-01-01 05:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00',
                                          '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00'],
                           'End time': ['1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00',
                                        '1900-01-01 06:31:00', '1900-01-01 07:31:00']})

records_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday'],
                                       'Direction': ['In', 'Out', 'In', 'Out', 'In'],
                                       'Reference time': ['1900-01-01 05:16:54', '1900-01-01 06:04:00', '1900-01-01 05:54:00',
                                              '1900-01-01 06:05:45', '1900-01-01 06:31:00']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are aiming for but perhaps this will help:

```
import pandas as pd

# First DataFrame
period_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday'],
                          'Direction': ['In', 'Out', 'In', 'Out', 'In'],
                          'Period': ['Period 1', 'Period 2', 'Period 3', 'Period 2', 'Period 1'],
                          'Start time': ['1900-01-01 05:01:00', '1900-01-01 05:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00'],
                          'End time': ['1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:01:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00', '1900-01-01 06:31:00', '1900-01-01 07:31:00']})

# Second DataFrame
records_df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday', 'Weekday'],
                           'Direction': ['In', 'Out', 'In', 'Out', 'In'],
                           'Reference time': ['1900-01-01 05:16:54', '1900-01-01 06:04:00', '1900-01-01 05:54:00', '1900-01-01 06:05:45', '1900-01-01 06:31:00']})

# Convert time columns to datetime objects
period_df['Start time'] = pd.to_datetime(period_df['Start time'])
period_df['End time'] = pd.to_datetime(period_df['End time'])
records_df['Reference time'] = pd.to_datetime(records_df['Reference time'])

# Function to find the period for each record
def find_period(record):
    for _, period in period_df.iterrows():
        if record['Day'] == period['Day'] and record['Direction'] == period['Direction'] and period['Start time'] <= record['Reference time'] <= period['End time']:
            return period['Period']
    return None

# Apply the find_period function to each row in records_df
records_df['Period'] = records_df.apply(find_period, axis=1)

print(records_df)
```

**result**

```
   Day     Direction Reference  time      Period
0  Weekday        In 1900-01-01 05:16:54  Period 1
1  Weekday       Out 1900-01-01 06:04:00  Period 2
2  Weekday        In 1900-01-01 05:54:00  Period 1
3  Weekday       Out 1900-01-01 06:05:45  Period 2
4  Weekday        In 1900-01-01 06:31:00  Period 3
```